# how to highlight pandas data frame on selected rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-slicing, pandas-styles

I have the data like this:

```
df:


    A-A      A-B    A-C      A-D     A-E
Tg  0.37    10.24   5.02    0.63    20.30
USL 0.39    10.26   5.04    0.65    20.32
LSL 0.35    10.22   5.00    0.63    20.28
1   0.35    10.23   5.05    0.65    20.45
2   0.36    10.19   5.07    0.67    20.25
3   0.34    10.25   5.03    0.66    20.33
4   0.35    10.20   5.08    0.69    20.22
5   0.33    10.17   5.05    0.62    20.40
Max 0.36    10.25   5.08    0.69    20.45
Min 0.33    10.17   5.03    0.62    20.22
```

I would like to color-highlight the data (index 1-5 in this df) by comparing Max and Min of the data (last two rows) to USL and LSL respectively. `if Max > USL or Min < LSL`, I would like to highlight the corresponding data points as red. `if Max == USL or Min == LSL`, corresponding data point as yellow and otherwise everything green.

I tried this :

```
highlight = np.where(df.loc['Max']>df.loc['USL'], 'background-color: red', '')
df.style.apply(lambda _: highlight)
```

but i get the error:

```
ValueError: Function <function <lambda> at 0x7fb681b601f0> created invalid index labels.
Usually, this is the result of the function returning a Series which contains invalid labels, or returning an incorrectly shaped, list-like object which cannot be mapped to labels, possibly due to applying the function along the wrong axis.
Result index has shape: (5,)
Expected index shape:   (10,)

Out[58]:
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x7fb681b52e20>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom function for create DataFrame of styles by conditions:

```
#changed data for test
print (df)
      A-A    A-B   A-C    A-D
Tg   0.37  10.24  5.02   0.63
USL  0.39  10.26  5.04   0.65
LSL  0.33   0.22  5.00  10.63
1    0.35  10.23  5.05   0.65
2    0.36  10.19  5.07   0.67
3    0.34  10.25  5.03   0.66
4    0.35  10.20  5.08   0.69
5    0.33  10.17  5.05   0.62
Max  0.36  10.25  5.08   0.69
Min  0.33  10.17  5.03   0.62
```

---

```
def hightlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color:red'
    c2 = 'background-color:yellow'
    c3 = 'background-color:green'
    #if values of index are strings
    r = list('12345')
    #if values of index are integers
    r = [1,2,3,4,5]

    m1 = (x.loc['Max']>x.loc['USL']) | (x.loc['Min']<x.loc['LSL'])
    print (m1)
    m2 = (x.loc['Max']==x.loc['USL']) | (x.loc['Min']==x.loc['LSL'])
    print (m2)
    #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled empty strings
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #modify values of df1 columns by boolean mask
    df1.loc[r, :] = np.select([m1, m2], [c1, c2], default=c3)
    return df1

df.style.apply(hightlight, axis=None)
```

[image: pic1]

EDIT: For compare `1-5` and `Min/Max` use:

```
def hightlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color:red'
    c2 = 'background-color:yellow'
    c3 = 'background-color:green'
    #if values of index are strings
    r = list('12345')
    #if values of index are integers
    # r = [1,2,3,4,5]
    
    r += ['Max','Min'] 

    m1 = (x.loc[r]>x.loc['USL']) | (x.loc[r]<x.loc['LSL'])
    m2 = (x.loc[r]==x.loc['USL']) | (x.loc[r]==x.loc['LSL'])

    #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled empty strings
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #modify values of df1 columns by boolean mask
    df1.loc[r, :] = np.select([m1, m2], [c1, c2], default=c3)
    return df1

df.style.apply(hightlight, axis=None)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it does not do what is intended; here is the output https://ibb.co/K5qQsyk

Comment: @A.E - Because always match first condition then all values are red. If match condition need same color per columns, right?

Comment: @A.E - added changed data for testing, then got also green and yellow columns

Comment: can you edit your code to reflect this? basically to show three colors based on three conditions?

Comment: @A.E - sure, answer was edited.

Comment: @A.E -  link is wrong, can you re post?

Comment: @jezarael, please use this link https://ibb.co/Z8Mbpkd

Comment: @A.E - Answer was edited.

Comment: i have one more question. In my actual project, I have a class that holds the data and analysis. How can I add your highlight function into the class method? here is part of my class `class Analysis():
    def __init__(self, file_dir):
        self.path = file_dir
    
    def getData(self):
        return pd.read_csv(self.path)
        index = df['Info']
    
    def getStd(self):
        return self.getData().loc['1':'5'].apply(lambda x: x.std())`

Comment: @A.E - Unfrotuantely no idea, sorry.